# Adding a Map Layer in Windows Phone from XAML

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, maps, windows-phone, layer

I was wondering if there's a way to add a new Layer to a Map in Windows Phone 8, just using XAML.
I know how to do it using C#, it's kinda simple.

But i'd love to know if somehow I can bind a layer to my map. Thing is, I have this project and I just started to use MVVM, more specifically MVVM Cross. The app displays a user's friends information on a map and a list, and since i'm binding that information to the list, it's worth the shot to know if I can create a layer with the same information in my ViewModel and let my map bind this layer in the View.

So is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MapItemsControl from the phone toolkit to bind your list.

Comment: Seems that'll do it, but now I'm stuck in trying to set the GeoCoordinate value for each PushPin, since System.Device.Location doesn't exist for PCL Libraries, any recommendation of how could I set this value without having the GeoCoordinate class?

Comment: The easiest is probably just to use a create a Converter to convert from your custom location class to GeoCoordinate

Comment: I think so too, turns out there IS a MvxCoordinates with the same things that a GeoCoordinate has, but it's not working, so I'll convert it myself